# Get woocommerce order total with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the snippet from the woothemes that can be found [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/).

Here's the code for front-end:

```
<?php global $woocommerce; ?>

<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
```

and for backend (functions.php)

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();

    ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    <?php

    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;

}
```

I want to get the order total that can be found after adding coupon code.

```
<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
```

The code above will just display the total amount of cart when adding a product, but not the total order. How can I display the total order with discount when adding product to cart?